# CustomOAuth2Error at URL (redirect_url_mismatch) Bad Request

Tags: django

Error occurs at that block of code:
`class GoogleCalendarRedirectView(View):

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    state_from_session = request.session.get('state')
    print(f"Stored State in Session: {state_from_session}")

    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        'client_secret.json',
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events'],
        state=state_from_session
    )
    flow.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000/en/accounts/rest/v1/calendar/redirect/'


    authorization_response = request.build_absolute_uri()
    **flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)**


    return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/accounts/rest/v1/calendar/events/')`
```

Debugger info:
`Stored State in Session: qQxetuwGbiBt9mwuz78jcVxQ39pkWZ Redirect URI: http://localhost:8000/en/accounts/rest/v1/calendar/redirect/ Stored State in Session: qQxetuwGbiBt9mwuz78jcVxQ39pkWZ`

client_secret.json redirect:
`"redirect_uris":["http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/accounts/rest/v1/calendar/redirect/"`

google console authorized redirect URLS:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/accounts/rest/v1/calendar/redirect/
```

I tried to edit and add new redirect URLS such as `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/accounts/rest/v1/calendar/redirect'`
but then this error occurs:
`Access blocked: This application sent an invalid request. You can't sign in because this app sent an invalid request. Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch`